# Show that eigenvalues are negative

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions

I have to consider the eigenvalue problem: 
$$ L[u] := \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}= λu,x \in (0,1)\quad  u(0)-\frac{du}{dx}(0)=0, u(1)=0.$$
I need to show that the eigenvalues are negative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we have $\lambda > 0$, then $u'' = \lambda u$ gives us $$u(t) = \alpha\exp(-\sqrt\lambda t) + \beta\exp(\sqrt\lambda t)$$
with $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$. Now 
\begin{align*}
  u(0) - u'(0) &= \alpha + \beta -\sqrt \lambda \alpha + \sqrt \lambda \beta\\
     &= \alpha(1 - \sqrt \lambda) + \beta(1 + \sqrt\lambda)\\
\text{and } u(1)&= \alpha\exp(-\sqrt \lambda) + \beta\exp(\sqrt\lambda)
\end{align*}
So we must have by the boundary conditions
$$\beta = -\alpha \exp(2\sqrt\lambda), \quad \beta = -\alpha\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt \lambda}{1+\sqrt \lambda} $$
that is $\alpha = \beta = 0$ or 
$$ \exp(2\sqrt \lambda) = \frac{1-\sqrt\lambda}{1+ \sqrt\lambda} $$
But this is impossible for $\lambda > 0$ as $\lambda \mapsto \exp(2\sqrt\lambda)$ is strictly increasing and $\lambda \mapsto \frac{1-\sqrt\lambda}{1+\sqrt \lambda}$ is decreasing and they are both equal at $0$. So $\alpha = \beta = 0$ and no $\lambda > 0$ is an eigenvalue.